# android access wizard for creating new activities

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, wizard

When I make a brand new android application using the wizard in Eclipse, I always get such organized features. Every time I update my android tools it seems there are more and more configurations I can choose from that auto generate some complex features in the android activity.

When I make a new activity, how can I get that wizard or browse from other configurations? The way I generally do it is pretty rudimentary, such as writing it myself or copy and pasting from other projects I've coded

thanks for insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click on project
2. Select "New"
3. Go to "Other"
4. Find "Android"
5. Select "Android Activity"